# What is the latest pd1 certification maintenance exam?

Tags: apex, developer, certification

What is the latest pd1 certification maintenance exam ?

Thanks,
Chinnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Platform Developer I now has one yearly maintenance exam that is released in the Winter of each year. [Trailhead has a table for when each certification receives a maintenance exam.](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?article=Certification-Release-Maintenance-Schedule)

As of this writing, the [Platform Developer I Certification Maintenance (Winter '21)](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/platform-developer-i-certification-maintenance-winter-21) is the latest (as of December 2020) and it is due by December 3rd, 2021 (*this Friday*).

You can always go to https://trailhead.salesforce.com/credentials/verification and check your credential status from there by typing in your Webassessor email into the "Certification Holders: Check Your Status" field. Trailhead will email you a list of your credentials and if any have maintenance due.